# Get the index of the clicked row index

Tags: mootools

I am new to mootools but have good knowledge on jQuery,
I am trying to get the index of the  on click.
Here is my HTML code..

```
<table>
    <tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Four</td><td>Five</td><td>Six</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Seven</td><td>Eight</td><td>Nine</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ten</td><td>Eleven</td><td>Twelve</td></tr>
</table>
```

And below is my Mootools code,

```
 $$('TABLE TBODY TR TD').addEvent('click',function(el)
                             {
                                 alert($(this).index());
                             });
```

It seems the code is wrong, Please someone let me know nay functions to get the properties of elements.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `$(this)` inside the callback is jQuery stuff. In mootools, to get the index of the current row you could retrieve [the collection of rows](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window%3adollars), [iterate them](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Array#Array%3aeach), and attach click event to all td children:

```
$$('table tr').each(function(row, index){ //row is the current tr, index is fairly self-explanatory :P

    //for each row, get its td children, attach the click event, and alert the 'index' (the number of the row)

    row.getElements('td').addEvent('click',function(){
        alert(index);
    });

    //or, if you just want to know the index of the row without doing something with each td, just attach the click event to the row        

});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/UN5jd/

**EDIT** : to get td indexes too, you could do something like this:

```
$$('table tr').each(function(row, index){
    row.getElements('td').each(function(column, i){
        column.addEvent('click',function(){
            alert("Row: " + index + " --- " + "Column: "+i);
        });
    });
});
```

demo2: http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/UN5jd/2/

Comment: But it is returning index of the row. I need the index of the <td> as well.

Comment: The title is "get the index of the clicked row" ;) to also get the index of the td, do the same of tr for each td. I ll make u an example later

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner way:

```
$$('table tr td').addEvent('click', function(e){
    var index = this.getParent('tr').getElements('td').indexOf(this);
    console.log(index);
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kt9aN/